# getting variable in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm new to react and having problem with getting variable from a child component(Link.js) in a sibling component (List.js) which is in the parent component(main.js).

I have a child component Links.js with onClick function

```
handleClick(myvar) {
    console.log(myvar);           
}
<a  onClick={() =>this.handleClick(["number", link])}>
```

I want to get ["number", link] array and use it in List component in the parent component main.js :

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="Main">
        <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>
          Open the modal
        </button>

        <Modal show={this.state.isOpen}
          onClose={this.toggleModal}>
          <Link />
        </Modal>
       <List here={getthearray(here)}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: If you have such more requirement  then should start to use `redux`

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava we can not said `easily`.It need to track the reference .Also it creating high coupling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is insert a props function (getter/setter) inside your child component then call it when you need to update your parent component.

```
handleClick(myvar) {
  this.props.parentFunction(myvar);       
}
```

Comment: Which means add handleClick(myvar) {
  this.props.parentFunction(myvar);       
} to Links.js and then use it in list component like this:<List here={handleClick(myvar)}/> but the problem is that I' m not using it to update my parent component. I think it's in this case my siblings component.

Comment: Your variable will be store in your main.js state so this will refresh your siblings to, however if you only want to update your siblings component i would use a dispatcher like redux/flux do.